# thread safe way of calculating moving average

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, moving-average

I have a library which makes HTTP calls to my service. I was trying to calculate running average of how much time my service is taking on an average.

Here is the core logic of how I am calculating "running average".

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class MovingAverage {

    private final Queue<BigDecimal> window = new ArrayDeque<BigDecimal>();
    private final int period;
    private BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    public MovingAverage(int period) {
        this.period = period;
    }

    public void add(BigDecimal num) {
        sum = sum.add(num);
        window.add(num);
        if (window.size() > period) {
            sum = sum.subtract(window.remove());
        }
    }

    public BigDecimal getAverage() {
        if (window.isEmpty()) return BigDecimal.ZERO;
        BigDecimal divisor = BigDecimal.valueOf(window.size());
        return sum.divide(divisor, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }
}
```

Is this code thread safe because this is being called from multithreaded program? If not how can I make this multithreaded.

I want to make sure this running average calculation is fast since this library runs under very heavy load so this should not increase the overall latency. Also I doubt I even need to use `BigDecimal` here, `double` or `long` might work here.

Comment: From the ArrayDeque API: "They are not thread-safe; in the absence of external synchronization, they do not support concurrent access by multiple threads."  I don't see you externally synchronized anything, so...

Comment: Do you have to use BigDecimal?  Looks like you're creating and destroying three BigDecimal objects for each `movingAverage.add(...)` call.  If you could use `long` and a `long[]` array or `double` and a `double[]` array, then it'd go a whole lot faster.

Comment: @jameslarge Can you provide an example how this will look like with `long` or `double`?

Answer (score 1):

this code is not thread safe, imagine next sequence:

```
initial state: MovingAverage queue is empty
thread 1: calls add(1), sum is 1, window size is 1
thread 2: calls add(1), pauses after sum = sum.add(num), sum is 2, window size is 1
thread 1: calls getAverage, it will return 2/1 = 2
```

another use case:

```
thread 1: calls add(1), pauses after sum.add(num), but before sum = 
thread 2: calls add(1), sets sum to 1
thread 1: continues, overwrites sum with 1, but should be 2, as windows size is updated to 2
```

the simplest way to make it tread safe - add `synchronized` before every method, but it will slow down execution

Comment: Slow it down compared to what?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis right, to non-synchronized incorrect version

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codahale.metrics ?
Then create metrics registry, and use for example histogram. It'll gives you average and more (p99, p999)

```
MetricRegistry metricRegistry = new MetricRegistry();
Histogram histogram = metricRegistry.histogram("stats");
```

And then in code:

```
histogram.update(operationTimeInMilliseconds)
```

Comment: If you do go this approach bear in mind that codehale histogram uses a reservoir concept and values won't be global.